# Cron jobs are not executing

Tags: magento-1.9, cron

In my website till the last week crons was working fine and suddenly stopped working and even stopped scheduling in the cron_schedule table. so i had truncated cron_schedule and executed php cron.php file through ssh and jobs has been scheduled but this jobs are not executing and status of this jobs are still pending.

Please Help me in debbuging this issue.

Comment: Might be some cronjob has 500 internal error after that it wont run any task , this might be the case

Comment: @ murtuza i had commented all custom cron jobs and still my cron jobs are default cron jobs are not working. any suggestions

Comment: try to run your cronjob manually by `bin/sh  /mahentoroot/cron.sh` via ssh and see what error is coming

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have two issues.

1. Cron jobs are no longer scheduled in the cron_schedule table; and
2. Cron jobs are no longer executing.

For #1, you should check whether someone changed the server configuration that called cron.sh. You want to ensure that some crontab on your system lists a command like this.

```
*/5 * * * * sh /path/to/your/magento/site/root/cron.sh
```

You can commonly find cron jobs by running commands like this. Note that you'll need sudo permissions.

```
echo Display system-wide crontab
sudo cat /etc/crontab

echo Display crontabs for all users on system
for user in $(cut -f1 -d: /etc/passwd); do echo $user; sudo crontab -u $user -l; done
```

More details available in this post.

**How to configure Magento cron job**

https://blog.amasty.com/configure-magento-cron-job/

Comment: How to test if cron working or not, i have schedule every morning auto clear cache, but not working.

Answer (score 0):

To schedule, configure and to now status of cron you can use cron scheduler module.

you can try this module --

> https://github.com/AOEpeople/Aoe_Scheduler

Answer (score 0):

There is a possibility that a cron process has got stuck

If you have shell access

`ps aux | grep php`

Locate process id next to cron.php

`kill -9 123456` where 123456 is the process I'd

Once the stuck process is terminated the schedule should refresh and resume

Comment: how one can locate process id next to cron.php ?